# Avoid using @ExperimentalMultiplatform in my code

Tags: kotlin

Using intellij i have to currently use @ExperimentalMultiplatform in all my mpp code... Is there any way i can avoid having to do this by setting an intellij or build.gradle option?

i am setting 
-version -Xuse-experimental=kotlin.ExperimentalMultiplatform

in my kotlin compiler preferences

sample

```
@ExperimentalMultiplatform
@Repository
class ClientUserGatewayImpl(private val repo: ClientUserRepo) : 
ClientUserGateway {
   override fun save(model: DetailClientUser): ServiceResult<DetailClientUser> {
    return try {
        ServiceResult.Success(repo.save(model))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        ServiceResult.Failure(errMsg = e.message ?: "exception had no message, check logs")
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What triggers intellij to require that opt-in? Is it `@Repository` annotation?

Comment: What do you use as Kotlin compiler? IntelliJ Idea/Android Studio/...?